# Warning trying to call BOOL method from another method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am following an iOS tutorial and my code is supposed to be correct, but I am getting an error which is not shown at the original tutorial code. 
These are the concerning methods:

```
-(BOOL)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section >0) return YES;

    return NO;

}
```

And here the piece of code supposed to be correct, but throws an error:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else {



        if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])

        {
            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
            {
                .../...
```

The error is shown at line

```
if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
```

And this is the error message:

```
No visible @interface for 'ToDoItemsTableViewController' declares the selector 'tableView:canCollapseSection:'
```

Is there any visible error in the code?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your method you are calling tableView but it should be tableview. small 'V'

Answer (score 2):

Declare

```
-(BOOL)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in your `.h` file.

Also make sure that, you typed it correctly (any spelling mistake can also cause the issue).

Comment: I was thinking doing what you propose, but in the tutorial it is directly declared in the .m file, like me.

Comment: @mvasco: yeah, I didn't notice the typo. That's the issue, if you are declaring any private methods no need to declare it on the .h file else you can declare it on the .h file also.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
```

tableView : V should be capital, please check after -(BOOL):tableview part

Comment: Thank you @suhit. Same answer than santhu. Typo from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare your method

```
-(BOOL)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in yourViewController.h file.